# Why does predict() require me to attach()?

Tags: r

I've been doing a textbook problem asking me to determine the 95% confidence interval for a certain x. The book comes with an R-manual reproduction sheet, but it tells me to attach() the dataframe. I know you aren't supposed to use attach() (see: http://www.r-bloggers.com/to-attach-or-not-attach-that-is-the-question/). Therefore I've been listing the variable names directly as DataFrame$Variable, and it's worked fine so far until I started using predict().
Here is what happens if I follow the r-instruction manual for the textbook:

```
> attach(TextPrices)
> new.data <- data.frame(Pages=450)
> TextPrices.lm1 <- lm(Price ~ Pages)
> predict(TextPrices.lm1, new.data, int="confidence")
       fit      lwr      upr
1 62.87549 51.73074 74.02024
> predict(TextPrices.lm1, new.data, int="prediction")
       fit       lwr      upr
1 62.87549 0.9035981 124.8474
```

Which is perfect. Matches up also with what I found on google for the same problem (http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/simple-linear-regression/confidence-interval-linear-regression). However doing it with DataFram$Variable messes everything up and I don't know why.

```
> TextPrices.lm1 <- lm(TextPrices$Price ~ TextPrices$Pages)
> new.data <- data.frame(TextPrices$Pages = 450)
Error: unexpected '=' in "new.data <- data.frame(TextPrices$Pages ="
> new.data <- data.frame(Pages = 450)
> predict(TextPrices.lm1, new.data, interval="confidence")
```

The above code give me 30 rows of fit, lwr, and upr. With an accompanying warning message:

```
Warning message:
'newdata' had 1 row but variables found have 30 rows
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is in the way i've been typing the code, not sure what the mess up is thought.

Comment: It's not because you're attaching the data or not attaching. The issue is that in your unattached attempt, when you're making `new.data`, you're telling R to set the value of `TextPrices$Pages` to 450. Replace that with "Pages", like you have in your attached example, and you'll be fine.

Comment: Changing it to pages doesn't fix it. I've already attempted that and it just generates the same problem.

Comment: From what package does `TextPrices` come?

Comment: It's a dataset protected by copyright. Effectively it is 2 columns (Price, Pages) with 30 rows showing the price of each book and how many pages it has. The confidence interval is for a book with 450 pages.

Comment: Never `attach`. Never use `data$column` when you don't have to (e.g., in `lm` when there is a data argument).

Comment: @Gregor What should I do if I don't use data$column? I'm already aware I'm never supposed to attach, but I thought data$column was the preferred.

Comment: Use the `data` argument, just like in the answer you accepted. `lm(Price ~ Pages, data = TextPrices)` works just fine. And it tells the model to look for a column named `Pages` in **whatever** the data frame is, whereas specifying `TextPrices$Pages` **insists** on using the `Pages` column *from the `TextPrices` data frame*, which is why you have trouble when you give a `newdata` argument with a different data frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making up a data frame since yours is apparently confidential, we can start with the following:

```
text_prices <- data.frame(pages = round(runif(30, 100, 600), 0), 
                          price = round(runif(30, 10, 120), 2))
```

Next, we try producing the model your way:

```
text_prices.lm1 <- lm(text_prices$price ~ text_price$pages)
new_data <- data.frame(pages = 450)
predict(text_prices.lm1, new_data, interval = "confidence")
#         fit      lwr       upr
# 1  81.56752 58.11610 105.01894
# 2  75.35715 61.54237  89.17193
# 3  72.56597 58.21001  86.92194
# .
# .
# .
# 29 79.96259 59.83313 100.09205
# 30 74.76402 61.16544  88.36261
# Warning message:
# 'newdata' had 1 row but variables found have 30 rows
```

Same error. So, considering the fact that it works when we attach our data, but not now, maybe the issue comes from the fact that we're entering our data into `lm` incorrectly. Let's try it a different way:

```
text_prices.lm1 <- lm(data = text_prices, price ~ pages)
new_data <- data.frame(pages = 450)
predict(text_prices.lm1, new_data, interval = "confidence")
#        fit      lwr      upr
# 1 78.46233 61.06646 95.85821
```

I'm not entirely sure why this fixes the solution, but this is how you'd go about it without needing to `attach` the data.

Comment: It worked. And I am confused why this fixes the solution. But thank you anyways.